# DFS - Checking Cycles

Tags: c++, depth-first-search

The objective is to find whether a undirected, unweighted graph is a tree, i.e. check whether it contains a back edge. I'm using a modified form of  White-Gray-Black DFS algorithm(which is given in Cormen and on the notes mentioned here: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~wdtseng/icpc/notes/graph_part1.pdf )

But somehow, it doesn't work. It worked once, but it resulted in a Run Time Error at SPOJ (http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07Y/).

**Update:** I'm now getting a WRONG answer for this problem. The code works for the sample test cases though.

Test case where it fails:

```
10 9

1 2

2 3

3 4

4 5

5 6

6 4

6 7

7 8

8 9
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool  M[10001][10001] = { 0 } ;
int color[10001] = { 0  };
long long int n;
bool answer=false;
void condition()
{
    cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    exit(0);
}
void condition2()
{
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;
    exit(0);
}

void dfs(int u, int p)
{
    color[u] = 1;
    for(int v=0; v < n; v++)
        {
            if(M[u][v] && v != p)
                {
                    if (color[v] == 0)
                        dfs(v, u);
                    else if (color[v]==1)
                    {
                         condition(); /* It has a backedge so it is not a tree, so print No */
                    }
                }
        }

    condition2(); /* It does not have backedge so it is not a tree so print YES */


}

int main()
{


long Z;
cin>>n>>Z;


// for(int i=0; i<n; i++) /* **Removed THIS nested loop to reduce runtime, successfully eliminated TLE** */
//     for(int j=0; j<n;j++)
//        M[i][j]=0;

for(int i=0; i < Z; i++)
{
    long temp1, temp2;
    cin>>temp1;
    cin>>temp2;
    temp1--;
    temp2--;

    M[temp1][temp2]=1;
    M[temp2][temp1]=1;

}


if(Z==n-1)
    dfs(0, -1);
else cout<<"NO"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two things. The array `color` should probably have 20001 elements. And you use `n` before it has a value.

Comment: Additionally, it is very helpful if you name your variables with something longer than `u`, `p` and `v`.

Comment: @sharth: I've updated the array color[20001] but however as you can see, n is assigned a value before function calls.

Comment: Please look at the first line of your main() function where you use `n` in the loop condition. And unless I'm mistaken, `color` is still an array of 128 `bool`s.

Comment: @sharth Okay, I updated the question now, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Since the graph is undirected, shouldn't you create 2 edges for each line of the input?: `M[temp1][temp2]=1;` and `M[temp2][temp1]=1;`?

Comment: @sharth: Okay, thanks for that, now I get a correct answer for all the test cases. But I get a runtime error (SIGKILL) on SPOJ. Is the complexity of my algorithm O(N^2)? If yes, how can I reduce it?

Comment: So, if it is runtime exceeded that you are hitting, then you should look into quitting early once `answer` is true.

Comment: Instead of using 2d array use arraylist(java) . I think vector(C++) are similar to arraylist in java ..

Comment: @sharth: I tried using a 'break' statement once a back-edge is detected, and I also tried using { return 0; } once a back-edge is detected, but still it results in a runtime exceeded.

Comment: Some thoughts: https://gist.github.com/sharth/7bc3805dba706b884c30

Comment: @sharth: I tried making the changes you suggested in my submission, but it still results in a runtime error. The time limit is 1 second and both N & M are <=20000, so I guess I need to use adjacency list. Right?

Comment: @user3125772: The problem says that the memory limit is 256MB. A 20000x20000 array has 400 million elements each of which is addressable (i.e. minimum one byte) so it can't fit in that limit.

Comment: @sharth: I was able to get rid of TLE by removing the nested-initialization loop. Also I noticed that the number of nodes are actually <=10000 so now it's well under the limits. But I'm getting a Wrong Answer now, and the code works for sample cases. Am I missing something? :(

Answer (score 1):

A graph is a tree if it is connected and `E = V-1`, where `E` and `V` are the number of edges and nodes respectively. So, you should be able to solve it in `O(V)` time as long you check that `E==V-1` before launching the DFS.

Can you test your program against a graph which is a path with `20000` nodes, with the node numbered `0` being a leaf and there being an edge from `i` to `i+1`? Please try to run it with stack size limits set to those on SPOJ(8MB IIRC) and ensure that you don't have a stack overflow. This is the worst case graph for the stack usage. If you do see the recursion being too deep, you can use a `BFS` instead to check that the number of connected components is 1. Alternately, you can use [path compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), which will make your runtime `O(n log n)`, but still easily fast enough to fit in the 1 second limit.

Comment: I've updated my question. The number of nodes are actually <=10000. I've updated my code accordingly (please have a look at it) and it gives the correct answer for small inputs but fails with bigger numbers.

Comment: On which node do I need to call DFS? I called DFS(0, -1). Which node should I call first?

Comment: You are calling condition2 any time a dfs finishes on a node. That isn't right. You should only be calling when dfs(0,-1) finishes. Anyway, since you have established that the dfs depth is acceptable, a simpler way to think if the problem is in terms of edges, nodes and connected components. You are being asked to check that CC=1 and that E+CC=V. So, forget about he parent node info that you are passing in the dfs and just use it to compute CC.

Comment: @user3125772 In my opinion, you should not hard code the parameters for the dfs() call in the main() function.  It is possible that the tree might start with some other shortest node.  In my accepted solution, I found out the least value of the entered nodes, and passed it as the parameter to the dfs() function.